# Why is all validation happening at one time

Tags: jquery, html, validation

This is the jquery script. The validation works, however if you leave one field blank and then click off the field onto the form, all the validation messages show up for each field in the form, not just the field that is empty. And how do you validate an email address in jquery in the format that is in my example?  Anyone any ideas? Thanks for any help in advance

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#firstname').on('blur', function() {
    if ($('#firstname').val() == '') {
        $('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
        $('.errorMsg').hide();
    }
    });
     $('#lastname').on('blur', function() {
    if ($('#lastname').val() == '') {
        $('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
        $('.errorMsg').hide();
    }
    });
     $('#email').on('blur', function() {
    if ($('#email').val() == '') {
        $('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
        $('.errorMsg').hide();
    }
    });
    $('#roomtype').on('blur', function() {
    if ($('#roomtype').val() == '') {
        $('.errorMsg').show();
    } else {
        $('.errorMsg').hide();
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is your html?

Comment: <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name" 
   maxlength="15">  <span class="errorMsg">First name required 
</span>
 </input>

Within the form this is what firstname, lastname, email and roomtype all look like, just with the id and label changed accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are using `$('.errorMsg').show();` which will target all classes with name = `errorMsg`.

make sure each validation only target the unique error message

Use `$(this).next(".errorMsg").show();` and `$(this).next(".errorMsg").hide();` for each input

example:

```
   if ($('#email').val() == '') {
        $(this).next(".errorMsg").show();
   } else {
        $(this).next(".errorMsg").hide();
   }
```

Example for email validation:

```js
$('.errorMsg').hide();

$('#email').on('blur', function(event) {
  if (event.target.checkValidity()){
    $(this).next('.errorMsg').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).next('.errorMsg').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="your email">
  <span class="errorMsg">Not Valid!!!!!!!!!!!</span>
</form>
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Do you know how I can add proper validation to an email address, so that it needs to be in the right format?

Comment: @Smith Don't close a input tag, there are tags that are forbidden to be closed: `img, input, br, hr, meta`, etc.

Comment: @Smith `<input type="email" placeholder="your email">`

Comment: I have <input type="email" placeholder="your email"> but it is still validating like a text field. Eg when any letter is inside it it is valid

Comment: @Smith take a look at this one https://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method/

Comment: Need to add, it cannot have a submit button. The validation needs to happen dynamically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157162/discussion-between-smith-and-daniel-h).

Comment: This code doesn't work either. When I click off the input field it doesn't do anything

Comment: @Smith reload, check the example, make sure you are not missing some id tag etc?.